# how to count winner for this table using join query

Tags: mysql, oracle

```
candidate table  
---------------------------                                

Id    Name
1     James
2     peter
3     robin
4     max

vote table
-----------------------

vote   candidate id   

1       1
1       1
1       1
1       2
1       3
1       3
1       2
```

how to count winner in mysql ....by this data base

Comment: What have you tried? Stackoverflow isn't somewhere to do your homework for you, but a resource for solving problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
c.name,
sum(v.vote) as total_votes
from candidate c
inner join vote v on v.candidate_id = c.Id
group by c.Id
order by total_votes desc limit 1
```

This will give the winner.

If you want to list all of them in order i.e. top to bottom use as

```
select 
c.name,
sum(v.vote) as total_votes
from candidate c
inner join vote v on v.candidate_id = c.Id
group by c.Id
order by total_votes desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose if there are two persons with same votes then there will be two winners for this situation you can do so

```
SELECT  c.*,
COUNT(*) `votes`,
t.votes_total
FROM candidate c
LEFT JOIN vote v ON(v.candidate_id = c.id)
JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) votes_total FROM vote 
      GROUP BY candidate_id 
      ORDER BY votes_total DESC
      LIMIT 1) t
GROUP BY  c.id
HAVING votes=t.votes_total
ORDER BY votes DESC
```

Other wise if you don't care for morethan one winners then you can use the ORDER BY with LIMIT technique provided by *Abhik Chakraborty*

### [Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/83847/3)